# Referrals from YouTube.com in Google Analytics, Coming from YouTube API?

Tags: google-analytics, youtube-api

Ever since I started embedding videos on my website using the YouTube API, I have been getting Social Network Referrals from YouTube. I don't have any links to my website on my videos or in the descriptions so I have no idea why that traffic would be coming from YouTube and where its coming from (full referrer is very generic)

I am wondering if that is just a reporting bug that happens when someone views a video on my website and then goes to another page. Or could I be doing something wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance for any insight into this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue :) One day in the morning I wake up in a sleepy mode and checked out my analytics and boom spike. But as you mention I wasn't able to find exact videoid which gives me this traffic. Long story short I just searched my domain name (without www) in a youtube and saw that 1 guy shared video yesterday and got 1K view for 24 hours. And I understand that it is that guy and video which gave me that traffic.

So, just try to search your domain name in youtube because video which gave you that traffic contains that domain ;-)